# Sending a tone to only one side of the headphones

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing

I am required to design a program on MATLAB that would create sound tones.

However, I have to send the tones out of phase with each other. I.E If the right ear is receiving the tone now, 0.5ms from now the left ear should receive the other tone. Hence the two tones are going to be roughly 180 degrees out of phase.

So my question is; how to program it such that the tone is first delivered to right ear then to left ear.

Is there a special MATLAB command for that?

Note: The tone is 1000Hz frequency.

Thank you.

Comment: So the tone is 2000 hertz?  Why not just invert the signal for one ear?

Comment: Sorry about not being more specific but yeah the tone is actually 1000Hz.

Comment: Ah, right.  5ms is half a wavelength.  Well, I would just invert the signal to one ear.  If you need an actual delay that's not exactly 180 degrees out of phase, just add a constant value to whatever number you're passing into the `sin` function to create the waveform.  Each  revolution of the sine wave looks exactly the same, so you don't really need a "real" delay line.

Comment: @RobertHarvey; yeah I am considering that but my question is how to tell matlab to deliver the normal signal to let say right ear but the inverted signal to the other ear.

Comment: Presumably you're generating two separate tones.  So your question is how to get the tones to each ear?

Comment: yeah to each ear separately.

Comment: A cursory look at Matlab forums suggests that sound support is pretty basic in Matlab.  Looks to me like you need to create a stereo wave file, and play that in Matlab using the `wavplay` function.

Comment: Okay great thank you. I will look into what you suggested and post an answer if I come up with one.

Comment: Creating a stereo file and setting one of the columns for the stereo file as zeros does give you sound for only one earplug!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wavplay is a fairly old function.  The modern audio player and writer methods assume your data is two-dimensional array where the first row or column is the left channel and the second is the right channel.

So, for example, you might create a 1 second, 1000 Hz tone, sampled at 44.1 kHz:

```
t = (0:44100)'./44100;
y = sin(1000 * 2 * pi * t);
```

You can then play it back in MATLAB in mono

```
player = audioplayer(y, 44100);
player.play();
```

or use it as just the left channel (switch the order of y and zeros(...) for just the right)

```
player = audioplayer([y, zeros(size(y))], 44100);
player.play();
```

or play the inverse on each channel

```
player = audioplayer([y, -y], 44100);
player.play();
```

To instead save to a file and play externally (or to read back into MATLAB later to play) the audiowrite function expects the same y and sample rate arguments.

```
audiowrite('C:\tone.wav', [y -y], 44100);
```

Comment: Great answer! but in this case you manipulate matlab by giving zeros coloumn matrix in the right/left channel. Is there any way to send sound to left channel only without sending (zeroes) to right channel?